# Why Don't We Use == To Compare Strings In Matlab

Tags: matlab, string-comparison

I know it's commonly accepted that using `strcmp` is the proper way to compare strings, but my question is why? According to the help:

> A == B does element by element comparisons between A and B
>       and returns a matrix of the same size with elements set to logical 1
>       where the relation is true and elements set to logical 0 where it is
>       not.

And all the toy examples I can come up with seem to work out.

Comment: Note: this isn't true as of the introduction of the "string" variable type in MATLAB R2016b. Your question only applies to character arrays, as it was written in 2013. With actual string variables (in double quotes), you can use `==`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strcmp` also checks that the inputs are class char, e.g., `strcmp('a',double('a'))` returns false, but `'a' == double('a')` returns true. `strcmp` cleanly handles empty inputs and you don't have to worry about the two strings being the same length either. And you can use cell inputs to easily compare multiple strings which is useful.

String comparisons can be a good deal slower - at least in current Matlab. But don't prematurely optimize your code at the cost of readability and maintainability. Only use `==` (or maybe `isequal`) in rare cases when you really do need performance and are very very sure about what you're comparing (use `ischar` and `isempty` first, for example).

Comment: The main difference as @Coconut Jones points out is that `==` is an elementwise comparison, and thus errors if the strings are different lengths, otherwise it returns a logical array which you'd need to reduce with `all`. `isequal` on the other hand is pretty much the same as `strcmp` for strings.

Answer (score 8):

`==` uses character-by-character comparison, so trying to test for equality with `==` with two strings of different lengths should give you an error.

Comment: An error is a pretty good reason.  You want it to say `false` if they are different, not error out.

Comment: Another (though minor) performance issue is that `==` would always compare all characters - while `strcmp` should (hopefully) return false upon the first non-equal character found.

Comment: @chappcj yes an error is reason enough, but my question wasn't "that's it??" it was "is there anything else?"

Answer (score 7):

Another small exception is with empty strings.

Using `'' == ''` in if statement evaluates to false.

`strcmp('','')` is true.